# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.image' has no attribute 'resize_images'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I am using pretrained model to detect objects by i am getting above error
tensorflow version = 2.2.0
keras version = 2.3.1

below is my code

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.0.1.h5"))
detector.loadModel()

custom_objects = detector.CustomObjects(person=True, car=False)
detections = detector.detectCustomObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path ,"image.jpg"),output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "image_new.jpg"), custom_objects=custom_objects, minimum_percentage_probability=65)

for eachObject in detections:
    print(eachObject["name"] + " : " + eachObject["percentage_probability"] )
    print("--------------------------------")
```

Comment: You can update your post as per standards. You could take quick review here https://stackoverflow.com/tour